# Jquery-Mobile: How to call the another page using ID

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have 2 pages with different id in the container page. first page have one button if you click on that then it will call one java script function. I want to implement the following one. In java script function, condition is true then only it will redirect to the next page using id. Otherwise don't redirect.How to do this please can anybody help me. is it clear?

CODE

```
< !DOCTYPE html> 

< html> 

< head> 

    < meta charset="utf-8"> 
    < meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    < title>Single page template</title>

      < link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
     < script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
     < script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>

< /head> 

< body>

< !-- BMR Screen page -->

  < div data-role="page" id="BMR_screen">

  < div data-role="header" data-theme="e" id="hdrBMRScreen">

  < h1> BMR Screen< /h1>
  < /div>

  < div data-role="content" id="contentBMRScreen"> 

        < div data-role="fieldcontain">  

             < label for="BMR_age">Age(in years):</label> 

             < input type="text" id="BMR_age" /> 

        < /div> 

        < a href="#BMR_Result" onclick="BMR_Cal()"  data-role="button">submit</a> 

  < /div>

 < /div>

 < !-- End BMR Screen -->

   < div data-role="page" id="BMR_Result">

       < div data-role="header" data-theme="b" >

            < a data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-icon="back">back</a>

            <h1>BMR Result</h1> 

       < /div>

        < div data-role="content">      

          < p id="W_Range">Weight Range:</p>   

        < /div>
    < /div>

  < script type="text/javascript"> 

  var agevar;


  $(document).ready(function () {   
    // Initialize variables 
    ageVar = $('#BMR_age');     
  });

  function BMR_Cal()
  {    
    if(ageVar.val() > 0)
    {       
        // then only it will redirect to the next page i.e, BMR_Result          
    }

  }
  < /script>
  < /body> 
< /html>
```

Comment: Your questions a little vague , could you post the code you've got?

Comment: i added the code please see it once

Comment: It's still a little hard to follow , are you sure you indented the code properly?

Comment: From looking at your code am I right in thinking you want an input form field which takes the users id and when they submit it you want to check if it's greater than 0 then they get redirected?

Comment: Sorry. now i updated the code please see it once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem is your assigning the variable when the page loads (before the user has inputted anything).

lets pop it all in the document ready .

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
// Initialize the variable by declaring it
var ageVar ;

function BMR_Cal() {
//then tie it to the input element AFTER the user has inputted .
ageVar = $('#BMR_age');
if(ageVar.val() > 0) {

document.location.href="yourpagename#BMR_Result";
}
});
```

Comment: Here what i have to write with in the if block for navigating to the next page?

Comment: @naresh updated the code . This should work . Rember to replace yourpagename with the *.html file but keep the anchor at the end .

Comment: @naresh Does it work OK? if so please could you mark the question answered .

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery mobile you shouldn't use the ready event. Use the mobileinit event instead, as init code for jQuery mobile runs before the DOM is ready. [See](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html)

Also, consider using [$.mobile.changePage method](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/methods.html) to perform a page change in javascript as it's safer and more configurable.